# PHP preg_match how to get from string begin "charcter=" and end with "&"

Tags: php, preg-match

i am novice in regular expressions.

i have:

```
$str = 'manufacturer=1,2,3&brand=5,4&filter=29-31+48-46,47&price=150-700';
$find = 'filter'; // for example. it can also be a price or brand or something

if (strpos($str, $find) !== FALSE)
{
$matches = array();
preg_match('/' . $find . '=???/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
}
```

??? represent, what regular expressions i must use and how i can parse from this string data separately with preg_match use like:

```
[0] = 29-31+48-46,47 // data parsed from "filter=" to "&" character
```

i cant use explode or similar command because the positions of parameter in string are not fixed.

thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a regex, it is the wrong tool for the job. Use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str):

```
$str = 'manufacturer=1,2,3&brand=5,4&filter=29-31+48-46,47&price=150-700';
parse_str( $str, $array);
echo $array['filter'];
```

This [prints](http://3v4l.org/tCflP):

```
29-31 48-46,47
```

Comment: Never used this function before. But that is pretty slick. Want to find a use for it now.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank You. Output is 29-31 48-46,47 (the plus sign missing), but that is no problem.

Comment: @glirpi - That's because `+` in a query string means space.